# How to work with am/pm with the time 12 or 24 in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, type-conversion

I'm relatively new to python and I've tried to implement program to prompt user to input time (##:## a.m./p.m.) and output if it's breakfast (7 a.m. to 8 a.m.), lunch (12 p.m to 1 p.m.), or dinner time (6 p.m. to 7 p.m.).

it worked for the most part but **when i input 12:00 p.m., it doesn't output 'lunch' as it should.** How can i fix this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Also how can I make it pythonic? Thanks again!

```
def main():
    time = input("whats the time? ")
    
    ans = (convert(time))
    if 7 <= ans <= 8: print ("breakfast time")
    elif 12 <= ans <= 13: print ("lunch time")
    elif 18 <= ans <= 19: print ("dinner time")
    else: return

def convert(x):
    h, m = x.split(":")
    new_m, time_range = m.split(" ")
    
    if "p.m." in m: 
        new_h = float(h) + 12
        y = new_h + float(new_m)/60
        return y
    elif "a.m." in m:
        new_h = float(h)
        y = new_h + float(new_m)/60
        return y
    else:
        return

main()
```

Comment: Right now, your code is set up so that 12 PM corresponds to a value of `new_h` equal to 24, which brings you outside the lunch range. You'll need to handle h=12 as its own case.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) Did you inspect the value of `ans` when `time` is `"12:00 p.m."`? That will make it very clear what's happening. Remember that the hour from 12-12:59pm is still 12-12:59 in the 24 hour clock

Answer (score 0):

Since you are giving the input 12:00 pm, the convert function returns 24.00.
In your main function there is no condition statement to check after 19.

Comment: @Sören That's how they teach us in school, so idk

Comment: @Sören aight, removed